Reshaping spatiotemporal dimension of mmap numpy so that it can be fed to ConvLSTM2D
I have this tensor of multidimensional array:
# read from memory-mapped files

# File paths for memory-mapped files
input_file_path = 'tensor_input.dat'
output_file_path = 'tensor_output.dat'

# Define the shapes of the arrays
tensor_input_shape = (12, 5, 120, 2, 600, 600)  # num of ID, num of channels, timeline, timesteps, height, width
tensor_output_shape = (12,)  # num of ID

tensor_input = np.memmap(input_file_path, dtype='uint8', mode='r', shape=tensor_input_shape)

# Debugging outputs
dbg(tensor_input)

Outputting:
tensor type is numpy array
shape: (12, 5, 120, 2, 600, 600)
dtype: uint8

The tensor input size is so large, that's why I use mmap.
The ConvLSTM2D keras accept 5D (batch, timestep, height, width, channel). Therefore I expect I can reshape the mmap into (batch*timeline, timestep, height, width, channel).
I can swap or change axis with np.transpose. But I'm afraid if I messed up the memory structure, mainly there is flatenned axis at batch and timeline axis.
Note:
Timeline is linear, timestep is offset of timeline. For example:
tensor[0,0,5,1,:,:] -> Picture at timeline 5 with timestep +1 (this is future timeline 5 with offset +1)
Update:
I got OOM crash doing transposing and reshaping:
import numpy as np

# File paths for memory-mapped files
input_file_path = 'tensor_input.dat'

# Define the shapes of the arrays
tensor_input_shape = (12, 5, 120, 2, 600, 600)

# Create a memory-mapped file for the input
tensor_input = np.memmap(input_file_path, dtype='uint8', mode='r', shape=tensor_input_shape)

# Calculate the new strides after transposing the axes (0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1)
new_strides = (
    tensor_input.strides[0],  # stride for axis 0 (num of ID)
    tensor_input.strides[2],  # stride for axis 2 (timeline)
    tensor_input.strides[3],  # stride for axis 3 (timesteps)
    tensor_input.strides[4],  # stride for axis 4 (height)
    tensor_input.strides[5],  # stride for axis 5 (width)
    tensor_input.strides[1],  # stride for axis 1 (num of channels)
)

# Create a view with manually set strides
tensor_input_transposed = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(tensor_input, shape=(12, 120, 2, 600, 600, 5), strides=new_strides)

# Reshape the transposed array
tensor_input_reshaped = np.reshape(tensor_input_transposed, (12*120, 2, 600, 600, 5))

# Debugging outputs
dbg(tensor_input_reshaped)


Individually transpose and reshape produce views. But a transpose followed by a reshape has to rearrange the data-buffer and thus makes an (in memory) copy.
